# How to hide keyboard while using UIPickerView with Swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have got a problem with my code because I am using a UIPickerView but when we switch from one textfield to another, keyboard is not hiding despite my code below.

I would be glad to have someone to help me.

(I have done research about this error but none of code I have seen solved my problem)

```
@IBOutlet weak var colorPickerView: UIPickerView!

public func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int{
    return 1
}

public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int{
    return list.count
}


func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    return list[row]
}

func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    self.colorTxtField.text! = self.list[row]
    self.colorPickerView.isHidden = true
}


func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    if textField == self.colorTxtField {
        self.colorPickerView.isHidden = false
        textField.endEditing(true)

    }
}
```

I would be glad to have someone to help me.

Comment: How do you display the picker view?

Comment: @rmaddy from storyboard

Comment: Maybe calling `endEditing` inside of `textFieldDidBeginEditing` is not supported / allowed. Have you tried using `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` instead and return `false` for `self.colorTxtField`.

Comment: @D.Mika I'll try that thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you are showing pickerView wrongly. You, need not to write

> func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField)

instead to show picker, just write this line in your `viewDidLoad`

```
self.colorTxtField.inputView = self.colorPickerView
```

Comment: thank for your response , now I have got this error *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7ff65b720ef0> should have parent view controller:<project1.Add2ViewController: 0x7ff65b5292b0> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7ff65c04e800>'

Comment: seems like your view hierarchy is not correct. Can you tell me how you are placing this textField and pickerView in your viewController ?

Answer (score 0):

Encountered same problem with some time and not much luck.. But some workaround I got from @D. Mika (thanks!) comment above is to implement `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`:

```
func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
    //or:
    self.view.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}
```

This solution somewhat does the trick because it hides keyboard that stayed from previous textfield, but it does not enable next tapped field editing *immediately* - so de facto user has to tap it twice. Still better this way then none